# User-specified Z matrix in lme

Tags: r, mixed-models, lmer

I have been looking forever about how to do this in R and cannot find anything! Basically, I am wanting to shrink predictors using LMM. So I have a set of fixed effects, X, and I have a set of predictors, Z, that I want to put a random effect on so the model is

```
Y=X*beta+Z*u+e
```

where u~N(0,sigma_u^2 * I) and e ~ N(0,sigma_e^2 * I). I thought I could do this in lme with

```
fit <- lme(Y~X,random=pdIdent(~-1+Z))
```

but I only get the error:

```
Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, groups) : 
invalid formula for groups
```

Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Is your set of predictors made up of dummy variables created from a single categorical variable?

Comment: No the predictors are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

N = sample size

```
group <- rep(1, N)
fit <- lme(Y~X, random=list(group=pdIdent(~-1+Z)))
```

Comment: Yea unfortunately it wants to see repeated values as group (such as FAMILY ID)